# What font collections can cover the entire unicode glyph spectrum?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I am using google noto fonts, falling back to system fonts (on a Mac), but it doesn't seem to have many of the "edge-case" characters in each Unicode block (like some Arabic extended characters, some many combining characters, etc.). I get that one font is limited to ~64k glyphs, and there are more than 100k unicode glyphs, so you at least need 2 fonts. But more likely you need a collection of fonts to make this happen. Here is what it looks like in my app with Noto fonts.

[image]

[image]

*That is just a **few** cases of missing glyphs...*

What do I do to be able to display these characters? What fonts can I collect that will cover *all* the unicode glyphs, so there are no empty boxes? If there is not one collection of fonts, how can I go about efficiently figuring out the fonts that contain these missing characters? I would like to be able to at least display all unicode characters, even if they don't all match the same font style.

Comment: I would start by investigating the unicode website to see if they display all glyphs somewhere and then use those fonts

Comment: The first set of combining symbols should already work on Mac with no additional fonts required oͦoͧoͨoͩoͪoͫoͬ [all above an o] As far as I'm aware [I'm no coder] this needs to be integrated in your app. I used to work support for an online game where no-one knew how to do this properly for Mac, so symbols that worked in any regular Mac app wouldn't work in text areas in the game.]

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). While there may be such a font, I fail to imagine a situation where it is crucial that everything character is in the same font. What do you want to achieve here?